# How to feed a nested collection in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Here is the code:

```
var list = mutableListOf<Set<String>>()
list[0] = mutableSetOf("bar")
list[0].add("foo") // doesn't compile
```

Why it doesn't compile ?

And how can I add an element to a nested collection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have set the element type of the mutable list as `Set`, which is immutable.

You should specify that it has a mutable set, for example: `mutableListOf<MutableSet<String>>`